# Retrieving BLOB from form and insert into sqlplus db using PHP

Tags: php, database, blob

I'm trying to get an image from a HTML form and insert it into an sqlplus db using PHP. I've looked at some solutions online and used bits and pieces but I can't seem to get it quite right.

This is what I have so far:

**Table:** 
(NOTE: I am only trying to populate `record_id`, `image_id`, `regular_size` as of right now)

```
CREATE TABLE pacs_images (
    record_id int,
    image_id int,
    thumbnail blob,
    regular_size blob,
    large_size blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (record_id, image_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (record_id) REFERENCES radiology_record);
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./Upload/UploadImage.php">
Record ID: <select name="record_id">
           <option value="empty">empty</option>
           <?php displayRecords(); ?>
           </select><span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span><br/>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span><br/>
<input type="submit" name="uploadImage" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

**Relevant Components of UploadImage.php:**

```
function buildQuery() {

    //Generates random unique id for image
    $imageID = generateImageID();

    // Connects to the db
    $conn = connect();
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pacs_images (record_id, image_id, regular_size) VALUES (" . 
        $_POST['record_id'] . ', ' . $imageID . ', \'' .
        file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) . '\')';
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    $res = oci_execute($stid);

    if (!$res) {
        $_SESSION['err'] = True;
        $_SESSION['err_msg'] = "Failed to add image";
    } 
    oci_close();

    header('Location: ../UploadPage.php');
    exit(1);
}

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/>";
    } else {
        buildQuery();
    }   
}
```

A few notes:

- This is not a major part of any project it is merely a small
  requirement that I am looking for advice on
- I realize it is not best practice to store large files in db, but this is what I am given.
- I've tried adding `addslashes(file_get_contents(...))` but it didn't help.

Just looking for some advice on how to handle this, what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Question does not involve sqlplus, removed tag.